# Не знаю как реализовать логику рандома начала хода

Tags: java, javafx, случайные-числа

В общем, я начинающий "разработчик" на java. Чтобы отточить некоторые навыки( работу с классами, функциями, объектами и т.д), решил сделать игру с помощью javaFX(но это как дополнительная инфа). В общем, игра "крестики-нолики"(знаю что банально, но начинать надо с чего-то), и у меня щас реализована логика хода через костыль
`int currentPlayer = (count % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;`, здесь идет факт того, что если число делится на 2 - крестик, нет - нолик.

Однако, хочется внести в свой проект немного "крутости" и чтобы  рандомно выбирался первый ход, то есть в одной игре был допустим крестик, во второй крестик, а в третьей уже выпал нолик(чисто пример). Но есть проблема, я не могу понять как реализовать эту логику. Может кто подскажет? Ну, или хотя бы дайте направление, чтобы набить шишек и понять как все взаимодействует.

Спасибо всем, кто откликнется!

Comment: `public static boolean getRandomBoolean() { return Math.random() < 0.5; }`. Если `true` - первый крестик, `false` - первый нолик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для генерации случайных чисел в Java есть класс [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), и его потомки:

- [`java.security.SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) -- обеспечивает криптографически стойкую генерацию случайных чисел
- [`java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) -- генератор случайных чисел для текущего потока.

Чтобы получить случайный выбор одного из двух значений 1 или 2 в дополнение к упомянутым, можно использовать разные методы:

```java
// nextBoolean
public static int random1() { return new Random().nextBoolean() ? 1 : 2;}
public static int random2() { return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? 1 : 2;}

// Random::nextInt(toExcl)
public static int random3() { return 1 + new Random().nextInt(2);}
// ThreadLocalRandom::nextInt(fromIncl, toExcl)
public static int random4() { return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 3);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Random

```
public int getRandom(){
    Random rand = new Random();    
    return rand.nextInt(2);
}
```

Код выдает случайные числа в диапазоне 0 - 1.

Comment: Блин, я че-то не додумался до использования этого, спасибо. Но тогда можете еще подсказать:

как тогда вклинить эту логику сюда или ее надо переписывать?

`if(currentPlayer == 1) {
                    imageView = new ImageView(krestic);
                } else {
                    imageView = new ImageView(nolic);
                }`

Comment: сделайте получение рандомного числа методом и включите этот метод в эту логику - if(currentPlayer == getRandom())

Comment: @doflare если ответ вас устраивает, пожалуйста, пометьте его как принятый.